# Complex conditional ordering in a query

Tags: sql, django, sorting, sql-order-by, django-orm

Okay, so there are two models - Event and Like. Event model has "business" field which links to the certain Business object, which further has "manager" field. Also, Event model has "when" field which describes the date when an event will occur.
On the other side, Like model has "event" field which links to the certain Event object, and also "person" and "date" fields which describe who gave like and when it was given to that event.

The goal is now to display on user page all liked events by targeted user, and all events which manager is that user. It can be simply done with this SQL command:

```
SELECT event.*
FROM event INNER JOIN 
     business
     ON (event.business_id = business.id)
WHERE ((event.id IN (SELECT event_id FROM 'like' WHERE person_id = 1)) OR business.manager_id = 1);
```

But, there comes a problem when that results have to be sorted, by already mentioned "date" in Like and "when" in Event model. The sorting behavior should be as follows: If the Event object derives from Like object then it should be sorted by "date" in that Like object, in other case it should be sorted by "when" in Event.
I think that this query would be way more complex once sorting is inserted there, so does anyone know the proper solution? I suppose that `CASE WHEN` or equivalent `annotate` command in Django ORM should be used, but I have no idea how exactly.

P.S. I don't mind if it's written in pure SQL or in Django ORM, as long as it solves the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Comment: I think that it's rather simple to understand, because what I'm doing is preparing a data to be shown on a user page, where there are mixed all events which that user liked with the other ones which he has created. And I have a problem with sorting them by like date (Like model), and "when" date in Event model.

Comment: @MikiSoft It's always more simple to the person who knows what they want, but most of us have an easier time understanding data than descriptions of data. As for your problem, you should be adding another `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`) to your query for the `like` table instead of using `event.id IN()` because that will give you access to the fields necessary for sorting... something like: `ORDER BY CASE WHEN like.person_id IS NULL THEN event.date ELSE like.date END`

Comment: @HartCO Thank you! I've managed to form a query from your suggestion! I'll post an answer now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of struggling I've finally managed to make it work:

```
SELECT event.*
FROM event
INNER JOIN
    business
    ON (event.business_id = business.id AND business.manager_id = 1)
LEFT JOIN
    'like'
    ON ('like'.event_id = event.id AND 'like'.person_id = 1)
ORDER BY COALESCE('like'.date, event.'when') DESC;
```

Now to translate it to Django ORM, I think that I'll post another question regarding that... Edit: [I did.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963436/translating-query-with-join-expressions-and-a-generic-relation-to-django-orm)